# how to prevent user to go to root folder from sftp via nautilus?

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, sftp

How to prevent user to go to root directory from nautilus? I have prevented from terminal but when I access my sftp from nautilus user go to root folder only. How to prevent that. I need user shoul go to its own home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use `chroot` (`ChrootDirectory` option in [`sshd_config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/sshd_config.5.html)). It is well described in manual page.